# How to use Input.GetMouseButtonDown inside of an if statement in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to use

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
```

inside of an if statement but it does not work. I've searched something and found that only inside of the Update method Input process can be done but the problem is that I used raycast and now I need to use this operation inside of my raycast statement. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: where are you calling this if? inside Update method?

Comment: Yes, my Raycast statement is inside of the Update method and I call this also inside of that statement.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly You could make a global bool variable such as `public bool MouseIsDown = false;`, within the `Update()` You can put your code with a check on mouse button

```
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
       MouseIsDown = true;
    }
```

Quick recap:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyScript: MonoBehaviour{
   
    public bool MouseIsDown = false;
   
    void Start(){}
    
    void Update(){
       if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
           MouseIsDown = true;
       }
       MyRaycastCode();
    }
}
```